# How to get a function variable into quotes and to return per result row result

Tags: mysql, function, select, quotes

I have a MYSQL function, 'isStat' which takes a date as input, I'm trying to understand how to quote a table or variable name so that it can be used within a query to set a result value 'AS column'

When I run my function directly I get the expected Boolean return values so I know it's working.  Now, I want to use that function in another query and return "isStatDate" for each row item as a column.  At first I thought this was an issue with the " or ' quotes when having my table column as the function input on SELECT.  And it was, and is (and perhaps not my only misunderstanding).

I would like to create a result column using my isStat function select call in my query but I can't figure how to quote it properly for the function... please advise!

Tried to CONCAT quotes around column name, tried QUOTE around column name, tried CONCAT to create a variable and put that in the function call (the CONCAT date values are correct for each row items date but still the inline function wont budge).

```
SELECT isStat("2019-09-09") AS isStatDate; //works
SELECT isStat('2019-09-09') AS isStatDate; //works
```

```
SELECT isStat(2019-09-09); //returns always false
```

```
SELECT thisID, thisStartDate, isStat(thisStartDate) AS isStatDate FROM sometable WHERE somecriteria=something ORDER BY whatever DESC; // also returns false for isStatDate
```

```
SELECT thisID, thisStartDate, isStat(CONCAT('"',thisStartDate,'"')) AS isStatDate FROM sometable WHERE somecriteria=something ORDER BY whatever DESC; // also returns false for isStatDate
```

```
SELECT thisID, thisStartDate, isStat(QUOTE(thisStartDate)) AS isStatDate FROM sometable WHERE somecriteria=something ORDER BY whatever DESC; // also returns false for isStatDate
```

```
SELECT thisID, @thisdate:=thisStartDate, CONCAT('"',@thisdate,'"'),isStat(@thisdate) AS isStatDate FROM sometable WHERE somecriteria=something ORDER BY whatever DESC; // also returns false for isStatDate
```

```
SELECT isStat(CONCAT('"',2019-09-09,'"')) AS isStatDate; // does not return the expected result
```

```
SELECT isStat(QUOTE(2019-09-09)) AS isStatDate; // does not return the expected result
```

Comment: just an update - if I do a separate query after the fact in php within my rows fetch everything works because I can quote the start date i.e "SELECT isStat('$shDATESTART') AS isStatDate;";

Comment: doing @thisDate:=QUOTE(`lg_client_shifts`.shDATESTART),(SELECT isStat(@thisDate) AS theDate) AS aDate results in the variable being quoted per row as the literal string I need to feed the isStat function, and yet it still doesn't return the correct value